# How to edit half-binary half-text files (for example, .ai)

Tags: binaryfiles, adobe-illustrator

I have a broken Adobe Illustrator file. The person creating the file embedded some images from a remote drive that no longer exists, and it makes Illustrator crash. I think the fix should be rather trivial. Part of the .ai file is text-based XML, that contains remote URLs:

```
           <rdf:li rdf:parseType="Resource">
              <stMfs:linkForm>EmbedByReference</stMfs:linkForm>
              <stMfs:reference rdf:parseType="Resource">
                 <stRef:filePath>\\123.45.67.89\path\to\my\file\niceimage.jpg</stRef:filePath>
                 <stRef:documentID>0</stRef:documentID>
                 <stRef:instanceID>0</stRef:instanceID>
              </stMfs:reference>
           </rdf:li>
```

All that I need to do is to write a short script that would replace all remote URLs with paths to the images on the local drive. The problem is that other parts of the file are binary. When I attempt to open the file with a text reader or with Python, it complains that the file is not UTF8-compatible, and would be corrupt if saved. Is there a way to edit only the text part of such half-text, half-binary file, leaving the binary part untouched? A solution using python, bash, sed or whatever you love most would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens exactly when you try to open the file? Usually when a linked file is missing, you get a message asking you what to do. If that's not happening something else in the file may be corrupted

Comment: When I open the file it asks to re-import all embedded objects one after another. Since there is about 30 of them and this process is extremely laggy, it took about 1h for my colleague to fix it directly. Should one choose to ignore the import and start editing the file as-is, the program crashes. It is not like I can't solve the problem with Illustrator, I just that want to know how to solve the program using scripting for future reference

Comment: Hey! Did you solve this? I just tried find-and-replace with Emacs. Emacs can write to the XML part without affecting the binary part, because the file opens and displays perfectly, but it doesn't work for the images, which appear missing. So I'm interested if you found a way.

Comment: @miguelmorin Sorry, this was too long ago. I recall that we ended up taking a different route, avoiding the problem altogether, as it was too cumbersome to solve